# When to use a while loop or if statement?

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, arduino

Can you give some examples of situations where a while loop and a if loop would be appropriate?

I am working on this project where an Arduino reads an analog input from a variable resistor. 
This is how I have it read the raw input:

```
int intputValue = analogRead(A0);
```

Then I convert the raw input into a number between 0 and 100 for percentage:

```
double percentValue = inputValue * (1.0/10.23);
```

So then I use this percentValue to determine whether the Arduino needs to send signal(s) through several of its digital pins. I have signals going to a 4 channel relay module. Basically my idea is that if the percentValue is between 0-25, one of the relays would turn on, hence only one digital pin would need to be activated. Between 26-50, two pins, 51-75, three pins, and 76-100, four pins.

Here's my question: Should I use a if statement:

```
if(percentValue >=0 && percentValue <=25){
   digitalWrite(pin1, HIGH);      //turns on pin 1
}
```

Or use a while loop:

```
while(percentValue >= 0 && percentValue <=25){
   digitalWrite(pin1, HIGH);       //turns on pin 1
}
```

Then I'm going to do a similar thing for the rest of the percentValue ranges.
Is there a difference between using "if" and "while" in this case?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If only works for one time, while works many times.

Comment: if is not a loop , though while is.

Comment: Just one small question. Why do you hate that poor Arduino? You are reading a value, storing it in a 16 bytes variable. And that's correct. But then you are converting it into a double (not even a float). Why? floating point variables are not a good choice for microcontrollers (since they don't have FP units, so they have to handle them in software). And that conversion is for what? For dividing it in four.... Simply write `if(inputValue >=0 && inputValue <=255)`. Your microcontroller will thank you....

Comment: The input is between 0 and 1023. I did the conversion to get the number to within 0 and 100, representing 0% to 100%. Can you explain why I should use float? I'm confused as to what you are saying.

Comment: `while(percentValue >= 0 && percentValue <=25) { ... ` either is never true or forever, as percentValue does not change inside the loop. --> Use the meaning of the loop function and write if statements. This makes your code simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Then I'm going to do a similar thing for the rest of the percentValue ranges."

This implies you should use an `if` statement, and not a `while` loop, especially if you want to do anything else with the device.

Presumably, this code will be placed in the Arduino loop() function, which is called repeatedly, giving you a loop. You don't want the Arduino to get stuck in a while loop of your own.

It appears that you want to light up different LEDs depending on the reading. You will want to turn off the other LEDs in the body of your `if` statements as well. Otherwise, the Arduino will just eventually have all 4 LEDs lit up.

```
if(percentValue >=0 && percentValue <=25){
   digitalWrite(pin1, HIGH);      //turns on pin 1
   digitalWrite(pin2, LOW);
   digitalWrite(pin3, LOW);
   digitalWrite(pin4, LOW); 
}
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I eventually put to get it working. I didn't think of the if statements' placement in the loop function, that they would just loop over and over. I did the same thing with the rest of the percentage numbers.

Answer (score 1):

**While loops** are used to run a specific code block as long as certain parameters are met. An **if statement** is similar but it will only run the said code block once but a while statement will run until told otherwise.

So effectively:

```
while(1 == 1)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Will print **Hello World** indefinitely. On the other hand:

```
if(1 == 1)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Will print **Hello World** once.

Just for fun since your understanding of loops is shady; a **for loop** will run a specified number of times:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Would print **Hello World** 3 times.

refer to:

[While loop](http://www.java-examples.com/do-while-loop)

[For loop](http://www.java-examples.com/loop)

[If statement](http://www.java-examples.com/if-statement-example)

[General Java Tutorials](http://www.java-examples.com/)

Comment: @user3211857 do not forget to select this answer if it helped you

Comment: This answer has no relation to arduino, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `setup` and `loop` function in your code, you can put `if` in your `loop` function.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  int intputValue = analogRead(A0);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly: 
  double percentValue = inputValue * (1.0/10.23);
  if(percentValue >= 0 && percentValue <= 25){
     digitalWrite(pin1, HIGH);      //turns on pin 1
  }
}
```